# IllegalArgumentException loading properties for listener in servlets 3.1 application

Tags: java, listener, servletcontextlistener

I have a `ServletContextListener` which is giving me an `IllegalArgumentException` when it tries to load the properties from the file. My code is as follows:

```
private final static Properties properties = new Properties(); 

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {        
    ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();  

    try {                        
        // Load MyProject's properties file.
        properties.load(sc.getResourceAsStream(sc.getInitParameter("myProjectPropsFilePath")));                                        
    } 
    catch(IOException e) {                                     
        Utils.printStackTrace(e);
    }

    // Write properties to ServletContext.
    sc.setAttribute("properties", properties);
}
```

The context parameter is being retrieved from `web.xml` but I do not understand why the `IllegalArgumentException` is being thrown at line:

`properties.load(sc.getResourceAsStream(sc.getInitParameter("myProjectPropsFilePath")));`

The stacktrace is as follows:

`08-Jun-2015 12:52:07.439 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-34] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class myProject.listener.SetPropertiesServletContextListener
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The resource path [\WEB-INF\properties\MyProject.properties] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.validate(StandardRoot.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResourceAsStream(ApplicationContext.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getResourceAsStream(ApplicationContextFacade.java:209)
    at myProject.listener.SetPropertiesServletContextListener.contextInitialized(SetPropertiesServletContextListener.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5158)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:697)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:579)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:455)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1554)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1428)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:885)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:343)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2451)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2440)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)`

Any ideas? I am using `Apache Tomcat 8.0.3`.

The appropriate part of `web.xml` is:

```
<!-- Listeners and parameters. -->
<listener>
    <description>SetPropertiesServletContextListener</description>
    <listener-class>myProject.listener.SetPropertiesServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>myProjectPropsFilePath</param-name>
    <param-value>\WEB-INF\properties\myProject.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: `'propertiesFilePath` was for display purposes: the lines displaying it have been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path should contain / as a separator because /WEB-INF/ remains the same in windows and in linux. You probably have wrong values in web.xml. According to [Java API specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29), you always use /.
This is wrong: `<param-value>\WEB-INF\properties\myProject.properties</param-value>`
Should've been:
`<param-value>/WEB-INF/properties/myProject.properties</param-value>`

Comment: But `sc.getRealPath("/")` is only used for display purposes. Should I be using it elsewhere?

Comment: Right, please post web.xml and folder structure

Comment: It has been appended to the question.

Comment: This is the message from the stacktrace which gives the path as you suggest: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The resource path [\WEB-INF\properties\myProject.properties] is not valid`. But reversing the backslashes makes the application work.

This is odd because I have another application which worked with backslashes!

Comment: @Gimby: Can you post your comment as an answer and I will accept is as such.